# How hard is it to determine ex(n,G)?

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness, approximation-hardness, undecidability

Define the [extremal Turán function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_graph_theory) $ex(n,G)$ of a graph $G$ as the most edges a graph on $n$ vertices can have without having a subgraph that is isomorphic to $G$. This function is [known asymptotically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Stone_theorem) if $G$ is non-bipartite but since it depends on the chromatic number of $G$, it is (at least) NP-hard to determine it. For some bipartite graphs the asymptotic/magnitude of $ex(n,G)$ is also known, but not for all. It is a conjecture that $ex(n,G)=\Theta(n^\alpha)$ for every $G$.

> Algorithmically, how hard is it to determine $ex(n,G)$ for an input $G$?

For example, is it decidable whether $ex(n,G)=O(n^\alpha)$?

Comment: Are you talking about simple graphs? If yes, then why it should be undecidable? What's wrong by enumerating over all graphs on n vertices?

Comment: I'm talking about simple graphs. The problem is that $n$ is not part of the input, but only $G$, so we are looking for a function (of $n$).

Comment: What kind of description of a function do you want? If you allow the function to be described by an algorithm or program, the answer is easy linear time in $G$: write a program that takes $n$ as input, hardcodes, $G$, and does the brute force search that @Saeed suggests.

Comment: @David Obviously I'm looking for a description that makes sense, but I didn't want to be more precise to allow different solutions. For example, it is a conjecture that $ex(n,G)$ is always $\Theta(n^\alpha)$. Can we determine $\alpha$ if it exists?

Comment: Here's a somewhat related paper: https://m.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/edita.pdf